# Android specifying application list for Intent.createChooser()

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm curious on the Intent.createChooser() method. I've done some research but haven't been able to find the specific answer I was looking for.

I have a requirement that depending on which application the user picks (either email or text) I'm to format the text differently. I'm OK with the chooser displaying other applications (I'd prefer to not remove options for users) but is there a way for my application to know which external application the user selected? From there I could maybe overload the initial Intent and send the properly formatted data.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm OK with the chooser displaying other applications (I'd prefer to not remove options for users) but is there a way for my application to know which external application the user selected?

No, sorry.

For that, you would need to create your own chooser dialog, using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`. Based on what the user chooses in that dialog, you can then set the appropriate extras on the `Intent`, along with the selected `ComponentName`, and use the resulting `Intent` with `startActivity()`.

(one of these days, I'll write one of these dialogs, as this question comes up a lot...)

Comment: Thank you very much CommonsWare!